# (color/shift) profiles in Scribus

Tags: print-production, color-profile, scribus, color-separation

I'm new to this stack exchange and I have a question. I downloaded some of the `ICC` colour profiles from Travis Shaffer's cool thing called *[[color/shift]](https://colorshift.theretherenow.com/)*.

As I tried to put the thing into `C:\Program Files\Scribus 1.5.5\share\profiles` from my `Downloads` folder, and when I open the app, it was something that looks *completely* different and not inside the colour management in the Settings.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure Scribus can convert a raster image using ICC colour profiles, which is what these profiles are actually used for - for creating separations of raster images for risograph printing.  I think this is rather a job for a raster image editor such as Photoshop.  Is it just the colour change you want to apply like an effect? Or will you actually need the the separations (spot colour channels) for riso printing?

Comment: Just a note before you try going down the Photoshop route, I can't actually use these profiles to convert to a multichannel image for spot colour separations. Not sure what's up there, possible bug in the most recent version of Photoshop. I'll need to investigate.

Comment: Can you please write more detail of what you are trying to do. And maybe show us a screenshot of your "it" that was "something that looks completely different and not inside the colour management in the Settings". Also please let us do an example with one specific ICC color profiles, not "some". Give us a precise link please and we can look at it. I have personally hacked color profiles to make them work in Scribus; it can be done, if the source material is suitable.